# Как вывести информацию в react-компонент из асинхронной функции?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, асинхронность

Есть асинхронная функция, которая возвращает promis с данными. Как вывести эти данные внутри компонента? В примере ниже в {data} ничего не выведется, так как функция ещё не успела отработать. Какие существуют способы это исправить?

```
async function someAsyncFunction() {
  /*...*/
  return 'result'
}

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState('')

  setData(someAsyncFunction())

  return (
    <div>
      {data}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо воспользоваться ф-ией [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

```html
<div id="react"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

async function someAsyncFunction() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/1');
      
    if (response.ok) {
      return await response.json();
    } else {
      console.log("Can't get data");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function datesInit() {
      const data = await someAsyncFunction();
      setName(data.name);
    }
    
    datesInit();
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <div>
      {name}
    </div>
  );
}

// Рендеринг
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, подход помог, но если написать анонимную функцию как вы предлагаете, появляются эти ошибки, не подскажете, почему?
Warning: useEffect must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up.
Uncaught TypeError: destroy is not a function
react-dom.development.js:18572 The above error occurred in the <App> component

Comment: А если внутри useEffect оформить как отдельную функцию, а потом вызвать, то работает:
  useEffect(() => {
    async function datesInit() {
 //...
    }
    datesInit()
  }, [])

Comment: @Unicode101 А, точно)) Забыл об этом) Дело в том что как и говорится в самой ошибке ф-ия переданная в `useEffect` должна либо возвращать ничего, либо ф-ию. Это ф-ия в дальнейшем отработает при размонтировании компоненты.  А когда пишешь `async` сразу, то ему возвращается `Promise`, который надо отдельно отрабатывать, чего `useEffect` не может сделать. Пример поправлю скоро